# How do I calculate XPS spectra for molecules to match experimental spectra?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, spectroscopy

I am trying to calculate the XPS spectra using the ICORELEVEL method in VASP, both using initial and final state approaches, for C1s and F1s electrons. My systems are single molecules.
However, my results are too off to be of any use. First, is this approach correct for molecular systems (I have seen this previously being used for bulk systems)?

Comment: You can check the VASP documentation: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ICORELEVEL, the method should apply a supercell

Comment: I believe for a molecule it doesn't matter as the periodic images should be sufficiently separated to begin with?